# InDesign CC: Can you spellcheck by style?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have an enormous conference book which includes over 100 pages of attendee names with their titles and companies. I don't want to spellcheck the names of the people, but I do want to check titles (Presdient, Grwoth, etc.). Is there a way to select only one style for spellchecking, or to remove a style from being spellchecked?

Comment: .. yeah.. gotta fix "Grwoth" :) Sorry... not that I'm aware of.

Comment: If they are imported then removing the placeholder for everything you don't want spellchecked should reduce it to what you need. Then again, the source material should be checked instead.

Comment: Creating a table of contents from styles works also, you could only spellcheck that then.

Comment: @KMSTR that's an interesting workaround, but I'd then have to manually stop and copy each and every correction back to the original location, which is excessively laborious. (and yes, the source should have been spellchecked, but we're presuming that I don't have access to the source.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Paragraph Style Options, under Advanced Character Formats, there is a dropdown for Language. Select [No Language] at the top of the menu.

Because there's no language selected, InDesign doesn't have a dictionary to check against, so it ignores the style.

So if I have a list of 2,000 people and I change the *Name* style to [No Language], ID does not spellcheck anything in that style. I can now spellcheck the rest of the story easily.

(The one caveat to this method is that ID also uses the spellchecking dictionary for hyphenation, so if you need anything in that style hyphenated, you have to restore the style to whatever language it was after you spellcheck everything else.)

Comment: Brilliant workaround! +1. Shame it won’t work with character styles (your names might well have been just a character style inside an “Attendee” paragraph style, for instance), where “[No Language]” just means “Ignore character style language and apply whatever language the paragraph style specifies”.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the misspelling to be "Grwoth" then Yes.

You use Find/Change (CMD+F) as follows:

Find What: *Grwoth*

Change To: *Growth*

Find Format:
*"Select from you Character Styles"*

(You do this by selecting the Magnifying Glass Icon to the right, which will open the Find Format Settings. It should default open to the Style Options tab, which will give you a drop down selectable menu from which to choose the specified style you've created.)

ALTERNATIVELY
You could search for the correct spelling of the word to see what is skipped.

ADDITIONALLY
You may select the boxes or text in which you know to have the error within and may run spell check on those objects alone.

You should also be able to use Find/Change here to you advantage. I have less success with the Find/Change Object tab which has numerous Attributes to search through. I would check Style Options first. You can further define the search by adding Attributes unique to your "Titles" - IE Fill color is separate from names.

Hope this helps and makes sense!

Comment: Sorry, I was using *Grwoth* as an example. In a list of 2,000 attendees from 1,500 companies, there's literally no way to know what's misspelled to do a S/R for it. Searching for "Growth" won't find all the "Grwoth" or "Gorwth" or "Grwth" or even "growth."

Comment: Wow, the answer you selected is a winner for sure. I don't know if you can combine the two, but may be worth a try to select all text by style and then run a search within. Just a guess though :( 

and a bonus +1 for you on the name! "Lauren Ipsum" -winning.

Comment: thanks! people only comment on the name about once a year or so. :)